# How to install Kafka on Windows?

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

I'm trying to install [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) message queue on Windows **for testing** purposes (not for production).

I found this article on how to install Apache Kafka 0.8 on Windows: http://janschulte.wordpress.com/2013/10/13/apache-kafka-0-8-on-windows/

It's a good article, but it's outdated, unfortunately.

Does someone know a way to achieve that?

Comment: Refer the official documentation, https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart On Windows platforms use `bin\windows\` instead of `bin/`, and change the script extension to `.bat`.

Comment: The link is no longer available

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok, it's finally not complicated :)

The only steps are:

**Edit** (2021/10) Latest versions of Kafka end up with an `AccessDeniedException` upon startup, and even when successfully started, throw the same error during log rotation. Kafka utilizes Java methods designed for Unix filesystem libraries, so [installing Kafka in **WSL2**](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/) is recommended (link to Confluent blog, but steps also applicable to Apache Kafka direct installation).

### Old answer

1. Download **[Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/)** and uncompress it somewhere nice (let's say `C:/Kafka`)
2. Install **[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)**

If using Cygwin, edit `\bin\kafka-run-class.sh` and at the end of the file, change

```
`exec $JAVA $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"`
```

to

```
``exec java $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp `cygpath -wp $CLASSPATH` $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"``
```

4. In **Environment Variables**, Add java to your **Path** System Variable:

[image]

That's it.. you can now run ZooKeeper and Kafka servers and [start playing with topics and stuff](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction)..

Comment: This did not work for me, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037263/apache-kafka-error-on-windows-couldnot-find-or-load-main-class-quorumpeermain/25772154#25772154) for my solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me as well, and neither did the solution linked by pennetti. I still get a `WARN Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)` during the setup and the script doesn't stop (tried with .bat and .sh files)

Comment: If you want to run from cygwin, and your JAVA_HOME path contains a space e.g. "C:\Program Files\Java\Jdk..." you will need to either change the kafka-run-class.sh script, or you can copy the jdk to a path without spaces, and change the Java home accordingly. The above script change did not work for me. What did work was changing the cygwin env variable to JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.1" and changing the above line in the script from exec $JAVA to exec "$JAVA"

Comment: Does not work: /cygdrive/c/ProgramPortable/kafka_2.12-2.3.0 
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
Error: Could not find or load main class kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer

Comment: WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) should be able to handle this at this point. No Cygwin.

Answer (score 23):

These are the steps I followed to run kafka on Windows

1. Install Zookeeper first (I [downloaded](http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.3.6/) v3.3.6) `zookeeper-3.3.6.tar.gz`
2. Extract Zookeeper and run this command in powershell/cmd `\zookeeper-3.3.6\bin> .\zkServer.cmd` Now this should up a Zookeeper instance on `localhost:2181`
3. Download Kafka binary version (I [downloaded](http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html) v0.10.0.1)`kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1.tgz`
4. Extract Kafka, time to modify some configs
5. Inside Kafka extraction you can find `.\config\server.properties`
6. In `.\config\server.properties` replace `log.dirs=c:/kafka/kafka-logs`
7. Note: Make sure to create those folders in relevant paths
8. Happy news: Now Kafka ships with windows .bat scripts, You can find these files inside `./bin/windows` folder
9. Start powershell/cmd and run this command to start Kafka broker  `.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties`
10. DONE!, Now you have a running Zookeeper instance and a Kafka broker.

Comment: why use zookeeper.properties file?

Comment: @asyard thanks for noted it, actually no need to config that, It's already configured and handle in zookeeper conf/zoo.cfg to store snapshots in C:\tmp" in this case it's doing nothing

Comment: @noelyahan There is no zoo.cfg in conf folder of zookeeper 3.4.9. There is zoo_sample.cfg instead. So there are an additional step required to create zoo.cfg.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov yes if not you can use the zoo_sample.cfg file to run the server ".\zkServer.cmd start ..\conf\zoo_sample.cfg" by providing the custom or available config file manually. But default is the zoo.cfg.

Comment: @noelyahan ".\zkServer.cmd start ..\conf\zoo_sample.cfg" did not work. So just renamed zoo_sample.cfg to zoo.cfg

Comment: @Sam-T thanks for the update, yes renaming the zoo_sample.cfg -> zoo.cfg and start the server just using zkServer.cmd should work.

Comment: @noelyahan Installed kafka_2.10-0.9.0.1 and zookeeper-3.3.6 - I am able successfully start both. But when I run a basic command: `bin\windows\kafka-run-class.bat kafka.admin.TopicCommand --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list` It **errors**: [2017-01-09 13:29:51,137] WARN Connected to an old server; r-o mode will be unavailable (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket). Its **WARN** so not sure if all is OK or not

Comment: I got `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003` i have IBM JDK is there any issue ?

Comment: why am getting an error as 'the file does not have an app associated with it...'

Answer (score 12):

You will probably find that Kafka comes with Windows .bat files under the *bin* folder to help you run Kafka under windows. However, those bat files are not updated since version 0.8.0 and some of Kafka's logic has changed (regarding topics, etc.).

I have tried two ways to solve this problem. One is to use Cygwin or MinGW to simulate Linux environment and run the Linux shell script, but there would be tons of other problems related to path names. The other solution, which is simpler and come with less trouble, is to use the corrected version of Windows bat files.

Please refer to this [blog post](http://blog.anilot.tk/2014/08/06/Set-Up-Kafka-On-Windows/).

Comment: may the given link provide an answer, please include the essential steps there to the post. It takes time, indeed, but unless you do that, this is better off as a comment.

Answer (score 5):

1. Download any **binary** version(I've downloaded kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0) of Kafka from https://kafka.apache.org/downloads
2. Extract it to any folder(I've extracted to "C:\Kafka")
3. Open Command Prompt
4. Go to the folder that you extract Kafka(C:\Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0)
5. Run this command to start Zookeeper

   ```
   .\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
   ```
6. Run this command to start Kafka

   ```
   .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
   ```

Now it works!

Answer (score 3):

In version 0.9.0. there are scripts in "bin" folder for windows. You can use them.

Answer (score 1):

With Chocolatey and Powershell:

1. `chocolatey.exe install kafka` -> installs Kafka into `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kafka\tools\kafka_2.11-1.0.0\` - your version might differ of course
2. add `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kafka\tools\kafka_2.11-1.0.0\` to your powershell path using `notepad $PROFILE`

After restarting powershell `kafka-console-consumer` should work as a command.

You also need to install ssl.properties with keystore and truststore. Put them e.g. into `C:\ProgramData\kafka` and put that into `ssl.properties` (please note the escaping of the backslashes):

```
security.protocol=SSL

ssl.truststore.location=C:\\ProgramData\\kafka\\kafka-truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=PASSWORD

ssl.keystore.location=C:\\ProgramData\\kafka\\kafka-keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=PASSWORD
ssl.key.password=PASSWORD

client.id=console-test
```

Now things like `kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server SERVERNAME:9094 --command-config C:\ProgramData\kafka\ssl.properties --list` should first pop up a firewall warning which you'd need to accept and then output a list of groups.

Answer (score 1):

**Running From A windows Shell**

As of April 2019, downloading Kafka from their website worked on Windows almost right out of the box

Downloading and using the windows version .bat files is described here:
https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

I ran into two problems when I did this:

1) JAVA_HOME was set to an unsupported JDK which led to this kind of error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object
>   exists on backward branch 209

Replacing with JDK 11 solved the problem.

2) The JAVA_HOME must not contain spaces which caused a 'cannot find the specified file' error. To fix this I used a shortened path like `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-11.0.1`

---

**Running From Cygwin**

If instead of the .bat files, you want to run the .sh files from **cygwin**, there is actually quite a bit that needs to be done, and even after that there may be problems that come up later. I can't really recommend this option, but I do use it as it's pretty convenient for some purposes.

If your JAVA_HOME path contains a space e.g. "C:\Program Files\Java\Jdk..." you will see something like this:

> bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 305: exec: C:\Program: not found

One solution is to copy the jdk to a path without spaces, and change the Java home accordingly.

If you don't want to change the JDK location, you can change the cygwin env variable as follows:

```
JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.1"
```

and change the line

```
exec $JAVA $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"
```

to

```
exec "$JAVA" $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"
```

There was another problem with the log parameters in kafka-run-class.sh and I had to replace the line

```
KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xlog:gc*:file=$LOG_DIR/$GC_LOG_FILE_NAME:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=102400"
```

with

```
KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xlog:gc*"
```

And even after all these changes I occasionally run into problems of Kafka shutting down because of an incompatible windows style path in the logs directories as described here:
[Kafka 1.0 stops with FATAL SHUTDOWN error. Logs directory failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168342/kafka-1-0-stops-with-fatal-shutdown-error-logs-directory-failed)
In short, you may be better off running the Kafka .bat scripts from the windows directory...

Answer (score 0):

I had configured Zookeeper and Apache Kafka on my Windows machine.

For Zookeeper, simply configure `ZOOKEEPER_HOME` and set the `PATH` also and then rename the `zoo.sample.cfg` to `zoo.cfg` and also change the path for `dataDir` in the `zoo.cfg`

For Apache Kafka, simply unzip and start the server from `bin` folder and start the Producer/Consumer from `windows` folder under the Kafka directory

Comment: You don't need to download Zookeeper separately. Kafka does not need `ZOOKEEPER_HOME`

Answer (score 0):

Kafka & Zookeeper have inbuilt Windows specific scripts as verified in the latest version. As mentioned in other other answers, the directory for windows scripts will be under `kafka_2.12-2.4.0\bin\windows` for Kafka. Zookeeper scripts are under /bin only but ending with "*.cmd"

There will be few minor additional steps you will have to do with ZooKeeper & Kafka like

- Creating zoo.cfg for ZooKeeper
- Configuring windows specific data directory for ZeeKeeper
- Kafka comes with default configuration file & it has very good OS specific handling i.e. `log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs` but it will create that directory structure under `C:/` directory seamlessly without failing.

It is also easy to quickly setup a Kafka Cluster with multiple Kafka Brokers on Windows with minor configurations. You can also create topics, publish/consume messages, verify topics/partitions etc. all from Windows Command Prompt. Here is a good detailed reference for the windows specific setup [Kafka Setup on Windows OS | Basic Installation, Setup, Verification, Cluster Setup, Storage](https://itsallbinary.com/kafka-setup-on-windows-os-basic-installation-setup-verification-cluster-setup-storage/)

Answer (score 0):

there is some useful command to start kafka & create/read some event on windows:
1-go to folder kafka and run cmd:

```
C:\Tools\kafka_2.13-3.5.0>
```

2- run zookeeper:

```
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
```

3- run kafka server:

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

4-create topic

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --topic <topicName> --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

5-create producer:

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat --topic <topicName> --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

6-create consumer:

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --topic <topicName> --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

7- read message from begenning:

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --topic topic-example --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```