# Apache Kafka error on windows - Couldnot find or load main class QuorumPeerMain

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I just downloaded Kafka 2.8.0 from Apache website, and I am trying to setup using the instructions given on the website. But when I try to start zookeper server, I am getting below error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain

My environment is Windows 7 64 bit. I tried to follow below e-mail chain: [Apache Email Chain](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201405.mbox/%3CCALUpvHXCtTKQFe59h_SN-6jZRScqWrgv0TWsjZ-HjV7AO19GOA@mail.gmail.com%3E) . But still it's having same issue. Can anyone guide me in this? As I am very new to this and couldn't find many information on Google/Apache Kafka email chain.

Comment: I ran into this same issue on Windows 7 64-bit and wrestled with it for a while before switching to [scala version 2.9.2](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/0.8.1.1/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.tgz) which worked with these [updated batch files](https://github.com/Anilot/kafka/releases/tag/0.8.1.1-UpdWinFiles). [This tutorial](http://blog.anilot.tk/2014/08/06/Set-Up-Kafka-On-Windows/) was very helpful.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Run these commands from your Kafka root folder:

`cd bin\windows`

Then run Zookeper server:

`zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties`

Then run Kafka server:

`kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties`

---

The gotcha here is to run the **.bat** files from the **/bin/windows** folder, so after you run your servers with the steps above and want to follow up with the tutorial, make sure you are running the correct batch files to create topics and whatnot, e.g.:

**Create a topic:**

`kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test`

**List topics:**

`kafka-topics.bat --list --zookeeper localhost:2181`

Comment: This worked for me, AFTER I moved Apache and Kafka to a folder with no spaces in the path.

Comment: Yeah. for me also it worked, after moving the kafka folder directly under C:\. It didn't worked when i extracted the kafka packages into C:\Program Files\ due to space issue in the folder name.

Answer (score 17):

This problem happened because you have downloaded wrong version of Kafka. On the [official page](http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html)

[image]

you have selected Source download. If you will download the binary, everything will work as expected.

Comment: I am using the Binary , running on Mac.The zookeeper is running in another window.But when I try to start kafka, I am facing the error above.

Answer (score 15):

I also got the same problem in Windows platform due to keeping the kafka_2.12-2.3.0 folder in the Program Files. I changed the Kafka directory from Program Files to C:\ drive root directory. It worked fine after executing the following commands:

First, go to the Kafka root folder:

```
cd C:\kafka_2.12-2.3.0
```

Run Zookeeper server:

```
bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties
```

Then Run Kafka Server:

```
bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config\server.properties
```

Answer (score 6):

Had the same error message even though I had the correct Kafka download for my Scala version.

It ended up I was running the non-windows sh file (needed to run the bat in the windows sub-folder) and was running from within the bin folder instead of the root.  Moving up to the root Kafka folder and running from there appears to have worked.

`C:\kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0>bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties`

Comment: Yes, didn't pay attention to the windows folder.

Answer (score 4):

I'm running on OS X and I found that having spaces anywhere in the path leading to my Kafka base directory led to this exact error message.  Renaming things without spaces solved the problem with no other fix.

As an example, my Kafka install was sitting at `/Users/me/Kafka Demo/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1` which caused that error when I tried to start Zookeeper.  All I did was rename things as `/Users/me/KafkaDemo/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1` and everything worked fine.

Comment: This is exactly what my problem was, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

The solution for windows OS is to do the following:

1. Download the binary version instead of the source version from the official website of Apache Kafka.
2. Make sure the JAVA_HOME environment variable does not have a space in it (by default it is installed in Program files), follow the official installation documentation for this.
   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39271_01/general.300/eid_getting_started/src/tgs_install_jdk.html.
3. Make sure the JRE path and KAFKA_HOME path do not have spaces in them as well.
4. Run the zookeeper before starting Kafka.

Comment: downloading the binary version solved the issue on windows. thanks man

Answer (score 2):

**First Thing:** Remove all blank space from the folder name.
**Second Thing:** Use Powershell

**Wrong Path:**

```
d:\kafka node> .\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
```

**Correct Path**

```
d:\kafka_node> .\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Thanks & Regards
Jaiswar Vipin Kumar R.

Comment: The problem was resolved for me by moving kafka from "C:\Program Files\Kafka" to "C:\Kafka". Didn't like the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the binary and follow the steps  mentioned in  below link. http://kafka.apache.org/07/quickstart.html

if you are facing errors like

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Quorumpeermain

copy `zookeeper.properties` from `config` folder to `bin` folder and `bin/windows` folder.

Now start the like
    server : run
    zookeeper-server-start.bat zookeeper.properties

from `bin` or `bin/windows`(if you are in window machine). It should work.

If you are still facing problem, below link would be helpful 
http://blog.anilot.tk/2014/08/06/Set-Up-Kafka-On-Windows/

Now try staring the Kafka server.

use the below command if you are using windows: Goto bin/windows and then run
kafka-server-start.bat ../../config/server.properties

if you are trying from shell prompt, goto `bin` and  run below command

```
kafka-server-start.bat ../config/server.properties
```

**Make sure server.properties is present in the config folder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I too faced the same problem and tried this way which was suggested in some comments above,

First I had my Kafka in `C:\Program Files`, Then I moved the `kafka_2.11-2.1.0` folder to `C:\` directory and tried the following command and it worked

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config\server.properties
```

P.S - ran the zookeper server before starting kafka

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded latest stable *Kafka* from Apache and instruction mentioned by *Matheus Felipe* worked as expected.

I downloaded binary option - **Scala 2.11** @ http://kafka.apache.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem used zookeeper-3.4.12. 
bin directory do not has .bat files and windows directory.
Just exist .com and .sh files. 
.com contain operation zookeeper execute. 
As you can see, that has to find %JAVA%.
So I just set JAVA=[my java.exe path]. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am using below mention command in windows environment.

```
Confluent_home\bin\windows> zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\etc\kafka\zookeeper.properties
```

if still you are getting the same error, then please verify you folder structure, Is there any space between folder name if yes then replace with either "_" or removed completely.

I was also facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Its bit weird. But replacing the root folder name to Kafka resolved my issue. It might help one or others.

Comment: Please don't paste any code as a picture when you can just cut and paste from your screen into Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidBuck Thanks for your suggestions. Highly appreciate it. I understand there should be policy to not upload the pic. If so please confirm

Comment: Many things in SO that aren't necessarily policy, but are definitely considered good or bad practice - this discussion mainly takes place on meta.stackoverflow.com. [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364809/7508700) for example suggests what reviewers can do to an answer containing pictures of code. There's some guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), too. Main rule for good answers is that they should a) answer the question, clearly and concisely, b) explain as clearly as possible why the answer helps (i.e. no code-only answers), c) post code as code.

Answer (score 0):

## Kafka docker for Windows OS

- Download the Zookeeper from page https://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html (3.5.8)
- Download the Kafka from page https://kafka.apache.org/downloads (kafka_2.13-2.6.0)

## Start Zookeeper

- Clone file `/conf/zoo_sample.cfg` to `/conf/zoo.cfg`
- Configure Zookeeper Admin (in `/conf/zoo.cfg` file) netty server port by adding this line `admin.serverPort=8099` at the end of the zoo.cfg file. This is to avoid the App default port 8080 conflict later.
- Run command to start `./zkServer.cmd`

## Stop Zookeeper

- Run command to stop: `./zkServer.cmd stop`

## Start Kafka

- Configure Kafka (in `/config/zookeeper.properties` file) with the Zookeeper admin port (e.g admin.serverPort=8099)
- Run command to start `./kafka-server-start.bat ../../config/server.properties`

## Stop Kafka

- Run command to stop: `./kafka-server-stop.bat`

### Topics

- Run command to create a topic: `./kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test_1`
- Run command to list all topics: `./kafka-topics.bat --list --zookeeper localhost:2181`

### Test Topics

- Run command to verify if a topic was created: `./kafka-topics.bat --describe --topic test_1 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`
- Open terminal to create an event to the topic: `./kafka-console-producer.bat --topic test_1 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`
- Open terminal to read the event from the topic: `./kafka-console-consumer.bat --topic test_1 --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

### Practical

- Write some events into the Topic (at `kafka-console-producer` terminal): **This is an event**
- Will see the events printed out from reading by the consumer (at `kafka-console-consumer` terminal) => **This is an event**

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

Change the JAVA_HOME system variable to the shortened pathname so it contains no space.

Instead of: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241`

Set:  `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_241`

This error can happen if any kafka .bat file references a malformed JAVA_HOME variable that contains space.

Setting the shortened pathname to the variable avoids the change to another path that contains no space and solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I used to meet the issue by running below cmd via git bash tool.

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Solution: I switched to cygwin tool (http://cygwin.com/) to run the same cmd and I did not see the issue any more.