# Unable to start Kafka Zookeeper in Windows

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have downloaded kafka_2.12-2.1.0 and placed in folder path "C:\kafka_2.12-2.1.0". For starting kafka zookeeper, I executed the below command in command prompt,

**C:\kafka_2.12-2.1.0>bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties**

I am getting error message as below,

**The syntax of the command is incorrect.**
**The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

I could not understand what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help. I am successfully able to start zookeeper and kafka server in Linux "bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties"

Comment: You can follow the answer at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037263/apache-kafka-error-on-windows-couldnot-find-or-load-main-class-quorumpeermain/65277228#65277228

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't forget that you're in a windows operating system so don't forget the dot `.` before the path `.\bin\...`

**Zookeeper Installation**
Locate your Zookeeper config directory. For example `C:\zookeeper-3.4.7\conf`.

Locate  `.cfg` file and Copy and Rename `zoo_sample.cfg` to `zoo.cfg` in `C:\Tools\zookeeper-3.4.9\conf`

Open it with any text editor like *Notepad++*

Find and edit `dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper to :\zookeeper-3.4.7\data`

In addition, add an entry in the System Environment Variables as you did for Java.
this means something like this

```
Add ZOOKEEPER_HOME = C:\zookeeper-3.4.7 to the System Variables.
```

add `;%ZOOKEEPER_HOME%\bin;`

Run Zookeeper by opening a new cmd and type : `zkserver`.

**KafkaServer**

Running a Kafka Server type

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

**Create Topic**

in order to create topics now you should do this:

- Now create a topic with the name “test” and a replication factor of
  1, as we have only one Kafka server running. If you have a cluster
  with more than one Kafka server running, you can increase the
  replication-factor accordingly, which will increase the data
  availability and act like a fault-tolerant system.
- Open a new command prompt in the location C:\kafka_2.12-2.1.0\bin\windows.
- Type the following command and hit Enter:

```
kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

**Creating a simple  Producer and Consumer to Test**

Open a new command prompt in the location C:\kafka_2.12-2.1.0\bin\windows and type  this for the producer:

```
kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

Again open a new command prompt in the same location and type:

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
```

Take a look at this [post](https://medium.com/@shaaslam/installing-apache-zookeeper-on-windows-45eda303e835) you will find it useful

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I found the actual problem here. The issue is not because of the command that I run in command prompt. But it is the convention of referring current directory in .bat file. In .bat file, the current directory is referred as %~dp0 instead of %CD%. And also the file path is referred in Linux file convension like "../config/zookeeper.properties" instead of "%CD%\config\zookeeper.properties". I modified them and executed the command in prompt. But the hard thing is, there are many places I need to change the directory path. Better I will download apache zookeeper and try.