# Apache kafka error on windows 10: kafka-topics.bat file gives syntax error

Tags: batch-file, apache-kafka

I am starting to learn Kafka. I managed to run zookeeper and kafka successfully. I am using Windows10 and my kafka version is 2_12-2.5.0.
My question is that when I try to create a topic from cmd using the below command:

```
kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic firstTopic`
```

I get the error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I know that the command I wrote is correct and the issue is the command inside the .bat file as I changed the command inside the kafka-topics.bat, the error changes. However I could not manage to run it. This is the content of kafka-topics.bat:

```
"%~dp0kafka-run-class.bat" kafka.admin.TopicCommand %*
```

I also tried to run kafka-topics.sh file instead of batch, but that gives a different error opening git bash, that is:

```
Error:Could not find or load main class kafka.admin.topicCommand
```

I also got rid of the space in "Program Files" while writing the path, so I don't think that is the reason of this error.

I got stuck and its hard to understand these errors as I am new.
Can you please help?

Comment: Error you got might be different but maybe this will help, Please check it out- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037263/apache-kafka-error-on-windows-couldnot-find-or-load-main-class-quorumpeermain

Comment: I suppose \` at end of first command line is added by mistake on writing the question.

Comment: I suggest to change the current working directory with `cd /D "directory path"` to the directory containing `kafka-topics.bat` and `kafka-run-class.bat`. The path of the batch files can be seen on running `where kafka-topics.bat`.

Comment: Not an answer, but I encountered the same problem and decided to use the WSL bash to run the Linux scripts, which works well. (Using openjdk-11). I had to edit my hostfile [as described here](https://boristyukin.com/connecting-to-kafka-on-virtualbox-from-windows/) though.

Comment: I solved the problem partly. I changed the directory to C:\ , don't think this was the answer, and I downloaded kafka binary version instead of source. .bat files work but I still encounter the same problem for .sh files. Good thing that I never intended to use .sh

Answer (score 0):

in my case it worked only when I moved Kafka folder to **C:** partition without any space in path
for example **C:\Kafka_sources**
and I used the below command to create a topic

```
kafka-topics.bat --create --topic test --zookeeper localhost:2181 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case:

- i removed the quotation marks in .*properties* for directories
- use forward slashes in .*properties* for directories
- i removed the dot-version numbers in directory path (don't know if that was deciding)
- but start with point and backlashes .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties)
- d:\ is possible !