Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain
While starting the server for Zookeeper in windows 10, getting this error
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain
Confluent community version : 7.6.1
Command to start : .\bin\zookeeper-server-start.bat  .\etc\kafka\zookeeper.properties
I tried starting the server but failed.
How can I boot up the server ?

This error can happen if you have spaces in the full path to those scripts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037263/apache-kafka-error-on-windows-couldnot-find-or-load-main-class-quorumpeermain

Hi @OneCricketeer,
Issue is still there.
I have checked the reference you shared but they are using Apache kafka 3.x where as I am trying to run confluent kafka community version 7.6.1.

Confluent simply redistributes apache kafka. The Zookeeper scripts aren't modified
