# Kafka 8.2.0 on Scala 2.10/Windows - Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I've just followed the instructions in Kafka's documentation with the following install:

Windows 7 64-bit, Scala 2.10.3, JRE 1.7.0_51-b13, Kafka 0.8.2.0 (for Scala 2.10 - kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.tgz)

Ensured JDK is in the PATH.

Edited `\bin\kafka-run-class.sh` and at the end of the file, changed

> exec $JAVA $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS
>   $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH
>   $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"

to

> exec java $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS
>   $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp `cygpath -wp
>   $CLASSPATH` $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"

as instructed in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115013).

I'm getting the error:

Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain

There's another question on SO however the solution is for a different version and I'm sure I've installed the right version.  Can anyone help with this version?

Much thanks.

Comment: It would help if you posted result of `cygpath -wp $CLASSPATH`. Pardon me to state the obvious, but resulting classpath misses zookeeper jar.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, not documented in the Kafka documentation at all but found with a little searching..

It ended up I was running the non-windows sh file (needed to run the bat in the windows sub-folder) and was running from within the bin folder instead of the root. Moving up to the root Kafka folder and running from there appears to have worked.

`C:\kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0>bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties`