# Error while creating topic in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka on window by Cygwin and trying to create a topic and getting the below error

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:/cygdrive/d/kafka/bin/../config/tools-log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \cygdrive\d\kafka\bin\..\config\tools-log4j.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:524)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<clinit>(ZkClient.java:57)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:51)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [file:/cygdrive/d/kafka/bin/../config/tools-log4j.properties].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread).
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

But the topic is getting created.
Can you help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the path you have mentioned is incorrect. As the message says File Not Found Exception.
Below is a sample code to send messages to kafka in Java. Assuming Kafka server is running locally.

```
`public static void main(String[] args){
    long events = 100000;
    Random rnd  = new Random();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
    props.put("partitioner.class", "com.pranjal.kafkatest.SimplePartitioner");
    props.put("request.required.acks", "1");

    ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);

    Producer<String, String> producer = new Producer<String, String>(config);

    for(int i=0;i<events;++i){

        long runtime = new Date().getTime();
        String ip    = "192.168.2." + rnd.nextInt(255);

        String msg= "Hello";

        KeyedMessage<String, String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String>("sentences", ip, msg);
        producer.send(data);
    }
    producer.close();
}`
```

Comment: i have not done any path setting can you help me where should i do that

Comment: Btw there is no problem with this message as it is only related to logging utilities **\cygdrive\d\kafka\bin..\config\tools-log4j.properties**. That is why your topic is being created correctly inspite of this error message. No worries.

Comment: thank you.can you  help me with the sample code of sending messages to kafka with java

Comment: Thanks a lot sahu.How can i view the messges in the topic whether they are sent or not

Comment: Use console consumer. It is present in bin directory of kafka.

Comment: Yes i tried it getting the below error
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL

Comment: Any sample code to fetch the nimber of messges in a topic

Answer (score 12):

Are you creating the topic using this command line from the [Kafka documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart)?

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test`

I encountered the same error when running that script in Cygwin, and I made this change in **bin/kafka-run-class.sh** to resolve the problem (similar to the Cygwin classpath solution referenced in step 3 of the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115013/is-there-an-easy-way-to-install-kafka-on-windows)):

Original:

`# Log4j settings
    if [ -z "$KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS" ]; then
       KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:$base_dir/config/tools-log4j.properties"
    fi`

To:

`# Log4j settings
    if [ -z "$KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS" ]; then
      KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:$(cygpath -wp $base_dir/config/tools-log4j.properties)"
    fi`

Comment: Seems like they updated that script to look for Cygwin but if you try to use Git Bash like me you'll still get the error :P

Comment: I was receiving the same error with git bash. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

I ran the `.bat` script instead of `.sh` script and it worked. I didn't have to change anything.

Initially I ran this script in git bash;

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --boostrap-server localhost:9092 --topic kafkaTopic
```

and got the following error:

> ```
> $ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --boostrap-server localhost:9092 --topic kafkaTopic
> log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL
> [file:/c/Users/admin/Documents/kafka/bin/../config/tools-log4j.properties].
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
>
> \c\Users\admin\Documents\kafka\bin\..\config\tools-log4j.properties
> (The system cannot find the path specified)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:557)
>       at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
>       at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
>       at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
>       at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
>       at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
>       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
>       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
>       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
>       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
>       at com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger$.apply(Logger.scala:48)
>       at kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$.<init>(Logging.scala:25)
>       at kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$.<clinit>(Logging.scala)
>       at kafka.utils.Logging.$init$(Logging.scala:47)
>       at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.<init>(ConsoleConsumer.scala:45)
>       at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.<clinit>(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
>       at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
> ```

I opened `cmd` and ran the command below:

```
C:\Users\admin\Documents\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic kafkaTopic
```

Output:

> `{"message":"Spring Kafka is cool","sender":"Sydney"}`

Worked nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

Using .bat worked for me. below are the sequence of commands:-

1. `cd kafka_2.13-3.3.1`
2. `.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties`
3. `.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties`
4. `\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

Output:- `Created topic quickstart-events.`

Comment: I had to navigate to the windows directory, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using Kafka 3.5, Windows and Git Bash as terminal, I solve changing the "kafka-run-class.sh" like this:

**Added:**

```
# GIT_BASH == 1 if GIT_BASH is detected, else 0.
if [[ $(uname -a) =~ "MINGW" ]]; then
  GIT_BASH=1
else
  GIT_BASH=0
fi
```

**After the CYGWIN initialization. Like this code:**

```
# CYGWIN == 1 if Cygwin is detected, else 0.
if [[ $(uname -a) =~ "CYGWIN" ]]; then
  CYGWIN=1
else
  CYGWIN=0
fi
```

**And then I change this:**

```
# Log4j settings
if [ -z "$KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS" ]; then
  # Log to console. This is a tool.
  LOG4J_DIR="$base_dir/config/tools-log4j.properties"
  # If Cygwin is detected, LOG4J_DIR is converted to Windows format.
  (( CYGWIN )) && LOG4J_DIR=$(cygpath --path --mixed "${LOG4J_DIR}")
  KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:${LOG4J_DIR}"
```

**To this:**

```
# Log4j settings
if [ -z "$KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS" ]; then
  # Log to console. This is a tool.
  LOG4J_DIR="$base_dir/config/tools-log4j.properties"
  # If Cygwin or GIT_BASH is detected, LOG4J_DIR is converted to Windows format.
  ( (( CYGWIN )) || (( GIT_BASH )) ) && LOG4J_DIR=$(cygpath --path --mixed "${LOG4J_DIR}")
  KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:${LOG4J_DIR}"
```

So like this it will convert to the windows format when you use **git bash** or cygwin terminal