# install kafka on windows - UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

Trying a POC, followed as suggest at https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os also a reference is there [Is there an easy way to install Kafka on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115013/is-there-an-easy-way-to-install-kafka-on-windows). I was able to run zookeeper 3.4.9 but not kafka 2.11-0.10.2.0, when i try to start i see 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=kafka/Kafka, offset=6` i have IBM JDK 1.7.0 installed on windows 7 64-bit version. Any suggestions please to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are trying to run Kafka build on a different Java runtime version than it was compiled.

Answer (score 0):

For **Kafka 0.10.2.0**, you will have to upgrade your java version to **JDK 1.8** or if you want to stay in JDK 1.7, make sure you are on **u51 or newer**.

For further reference on above, check the following link,

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#java

Comment: I have tried with even later versions of JAVA also no luck

Comment: Could you share the version of JAVA used ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your jdk 1.7 to jdk 1.8