# How do I install Kafka MultiBroker System in a single node in windows

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to install Multi-Broker System in windows in a single node. 
I have successfully installed Single-Broker Kafka System in windows and 
started the Broker and Zookeeper.

Now i want to install Multi-Broker System in a single node and facing 
errors in windows.

This is for testing purposes only.

I will describe how I go about installing a Multi-Broker Kafka System.

In the kafka installation folder I have copied 2 copies of server.properties file and renamed to server- 1.properties and server-2.properties inside config directory.

I have edited server-1 properties file as

```
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
log.dir =/temp/kafka-logs-1
```

Similarly I have edited server-2 properties file as

```
broker.id=2
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9094
log.dir =/temp/kafka-logs-2
```

I succesfully started zookeeper and broker 1 as done previously for single broker kafka cluster.

The command I used for starting the first broker is
\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties

Now i want to start 2nd Broker.

I used the following command
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server-1.properties

But i get error as below

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\config\server-2.properties <The system 
cannot find the file specified>
```

I have followed this Stackoverflow question for Single-Broker Kafka Setup.
[Is there an easy way to install Kafka on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115013/is-there-an-easy-way-to-) 
install-kafka-on-windows

Kindly guide me why I am getting the above error? Can we set up Multi-Broker Kafka  System in a single node in windows?

Comment: Unless your log directories are on separate disks, running more than one Kafka process on the same machine doesn't really have performance benefits.

Comment: Just for testing purpose..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about installing Kafka on Windows. 
The only reason this error would occur is if the file in fact doesn't exist in the location specified.

Also, You copied 2 files server-1.properties and server-2.properties but you ran the command with server.properties. Can you please verify if you have correctly created the copies of the properties file?

Comment: I had correctly copied the properties files.But i was giving wrong name of file.It works fine now thanks.