# running zookeeper on windows got INFO ZooKeeper audit is disabled. and ERROR Exiting JVM with code 2

Tags: windows, apache-zookeeper

i tried to run zookeeper on windows using the following command

`zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties`

and i got this error

```
     INFO Reading configuration from: config\zookeeper.properties 
     (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
     [2022-03-01 00:06:37,850] WARN config\zookeeper.properties is relative. Prepend .\ to 
     indicate that you're sure! (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
     [2022-03-01 00:06:37,850] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally 
     (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
     org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing 
     config\zookeeper.properties
        at 
     org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:198)
        at 
     org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:124)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: config\zookeeper.properties file is missing
        at 
  org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.VerifyingFileFactory.doFailForNonExistingPath(VerifyingFile Factory.java:54)
        at 
 org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.VerifyingFileFactory.validate(VerifyingFileFactory.java:47)
        at 
   
   
   
  org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.VerifyingFileFactory.create(VerifyingFileFactory.java:39)
        at 
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:180)
        ... 2 more
    Invalid config, exiting abnormally
    [2022-03-01 00:06:37,853] INFO ZooKeeper audit is disabled. 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.audit.ZKAuditProvider)
    [2022-03-01 00:06:37,855] ERROR Exiting JVM with code 2 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.util.ServiceUtils)
```

Comment: You should really be using WSL2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115013/how-to-install-kafka-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

The error message already tell you what went wrong

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: config\zookeeper.properties file is missing at org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.VerifyingFileFactory.doFailForNonExistingPath(VerifyingFile Factory.java:54)

It's raising error because it cannot load the `zookeeper.properties` file when running zookeeper.

Kafka bat files for Windows is one folder nested inside `windows` folder, so you need to step out twice with `..\` to point to the config directory.
[image]

This should work for you

```
kafka_2.13-3.1.0\bin\windows> .\zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties
```

And same thing, to start kafka server afterward

```
kafka_2.13-3.1.0\bin\windows> .\kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties
```

These commands should point to the `zookeeper.properties` and `server.properties` inside config directory of kafka at
**kafka_2.13-3.1.0\config**

Assuming that you didn't modify/moving the default config directory of Kafka

Comment: zookeeper is runnig but kafka server is shutting down
INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
INFO Session: 0x1000003f9f80002 closed 
 INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x1000003f9f80002 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
 INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
 INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
 INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
 ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.Kafka$)
INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:
First, your directory should be on the Kafka folder just before the bin directory on both steps:

To start zookeeper:

.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties

To start the kafka server:

.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm on windows, I had to change the bars to work:

from:

```
zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties
```

to:

```
zookeeper-server-start.bat ../../config/zookeeper.properties
```

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

this cmd works for me in windows.

```
C:\kafka\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start ../../config/zookeeper.properties
```

or try this (I guess you set your environment variable)

```
C:\kafka>zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties
```