# Unable to start confluent local services

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm using http://packages.confluent.io/archive/7.3/ > confluent-7.3.0.zip

```
confluent local services start
```

getting the error below even though the file is there. Please help!

```
Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\confluent.727246
Starting ZooKeeper
Error: exec: "D:\\Development\\tools\\confluent\\bin\\zookeeper-server-start": file does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bin\zookeeper-server-start.sh` script is intended for Unix execution.

[Confluent Platform does not support Windows](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#operating-systems)

If you use WSL2, it may work there. [How to install Kafka on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115013/how-to-install-kafka-on-windows)