# zookeeper service won't start

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Trying to start zookeeper service on command prompt, but have no response.

when I enter bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties some windows opens, after ~1min automatically closes and no other response or error is shown. Zookeeper is not running.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly6nZ.png)

I followed instruction on kafka.apache.org. Tried to use previous version kafka-3.3.2, but nothing works.

Comment: "Command prompt"? Windows does not run sh files. Use the scripts under bin/windows folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have Git Bash installed, which doesn't have Java on its PATH by default , needed to run Zookeeper or Kafka.

Use `\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start` script instead, as the Kafka documentation mentions for Windows users (at least it used to).

Or start with Git bash / WSL2 **terminal** rather than command prompt. Then you'll be able to see the error message better.

Related [How to install Kafka on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115013/how-to-install-kafka-on-windows)

Also, latest Kafka doesn't require Zookeeper, but you'd probably get the same issue running Kafka in Kraft mode